# Cryptopals challenge 6 incorrect results when computing key size

Tags: rust, cryptography

I'm working on the [Cryptopals challenges](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6) and I'm stuck on challenge 6. I've written the following Rust code to compute key sizes as specified in the challenge and I'm getting weird results.

```
fn get_keysizes(mut ciphertext: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<(usize, u64)> {
    let mut sizelist: Vec<(usize, u64)> = Vec::new();

    for keysize in 2..41 {
        let blocks: Vec<&[u8]> = ciphertext.chunks(keysize).collect();
        sizelist.push((keysize, get_hamming_distance(blocks[0], blocks[1]) / keysize as u64));
    }
    sizelist.sort_by(|x, y| x.1.cmp(&y.1));
    println!("{:?}", sizelist);
    sizelist
}
```

I encrypted the string `For each KEYSIZE, take the first KEYSIZE worth of bytes, and the second KEYSIZE worth of bytes, and find the edit distance between them. Normalize this result by dividing by KEYSIZE.` with repeating key XOR using `the cryptopals crypto challenges` as the key and passed the ciphertext into my function and it computed the key length to be 3.

Even though I've followed the algorithm in the challenge, I may have misinterpreted it.

I have no idea why its not working, I've read a lot of articles on how to solve this challenge but none of them follow the algorithm in the challenge.

Comment: I suspect you just don't have enough ciphertext / have picked a ciphertext that highlights a potential flaw of this algorithm. Two blocks of text encrypted with the same key are *likely* to have a lower Hamming distance than those encrypted with different keys, but it's not *guaranteed*. You may need a lot of ciphertext to know whether a key size with low normalized Hamming distance is statistically significant or not.

Comment: What's the `/ KEYSIZE as u64` good for?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The `/` operator expects arguments of the same type on both sides. `get_hamming_distance()` returns a u64 so that's why.

Comment: @trentcl The challenge (https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6) specifically provides the steps to solve this, I'll try using a larger ciphertext though.

Comment: And it suggests using the smallest 2-3 normalized distances, or using more than two blocks and finding the smallest average distance, to mitigate the problem I think you're seeing.

Comment: @nom I interpret Andrey Tyukin's question as "why are you dividing at all" (or at least that's what I'd like to know)

Comment: @Shepmaster No, I asked specifically why OP is performing an integer division with `u64` instead of casting both numbers to `f32` or `f64`. The division is necessary, because they use something like "the average number of wrong bits per byte" as heuristic, without the division / normalization the smallest `KEYSIZE` would always win. But right now, integer division only introduces noise and rounding errors. @OP: I think the hint *"Or take 4 KEYSIZE blocks instead of 2 and average the distances."* is there for a good reason, the task feels as if it would require that kind of tweaking.

Comment: ...and by the way: `u64`, for hamming distance between two blocks with few hundred bytes max? Seems a bit excessive.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thank you, I'll change that to a f64. And that `u64` is surely excessive, I don't know why I chose that, I'll fix it. And let me change my algorithm and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't adequately describe the correct behavior; it's my opinion that the code does not have a bug (but it may not be the algorithm you wanted to write).